# Inline list-style-type not overriding external style rules

Tags: html, css

I applied a list-style-type to an unordered list that is an image. As you can see below, my unordered list has an additional unordered list in it.

I would like for the nested unordered list to have a 'circle' list-style-type, that is why I used an inline style for the nested unordered list.

The problem I am having is it is still displaying the green-checkmark for the list-style in the nested list, instead of the circle list-style.

So far, every time I used inline css it overrode any external style rules, that is why I am not sure what I should do in this case, I appreciate any advice.

css

```
ul{list-style-image:url(images/green-checkmark.png);}
```

Markup

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>animals
         <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
           <li>cats</li>
           <li>dogs</li>
           <li>rats</li>
            <li>hogs</li>
            <li>snakes</li>
            <li>frogs</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>onions</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of using inline styles, why not just use `class` or a more specific selector, like `ul ul { ... }`?

Comment: That's because you need to override `list-style-image` aswell as setting `list-style-type`.

Comment: Zhihao thanks for the advice, you're right, I should have applied a class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<ul style="list-style-type:circle; list-style-image: none;">`.

The two properties are different. If you have set any `list-style-image` it overrides `list-style-type`, the latter only being used if the image is *not available* (as a back-up). So to force the image to not be used, it needs to be explicitly told to not use the image in this case.

You should actually be able to set it up like so:

```
ul{
  list-style-image:url(images/green-checkmark.png);
  list-style-type:circle; /* back-up */
}
```

Then if doing inline: `<ul style="list-style-image: none;">`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried overriding list-style-image aswell? e.g. `style="list-style-image: none; list-style-type:circle;"`.

Zhihao is right though - this would be better done as a class or more specific selector in your external CSS.